# Is there a fast method for comparing values of 2 lists up to a specified index in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### I want to know how to automate this part:

```
if n + list1[0] == list2[0] and n + list1[1] == list2[1] and n + list1[2] == list2[2]:
```

#### In this code:

```
def find_first_match(amount_of_checks):
    for n in range(range_start, range_end):
         if n + list1[0] == list2[0] and n + list1[1] == list2[1] and n + list1[2] == list2[2]:
            first_match = n
            return first_match
```

Meaning perform specified amount of `n + list1[index] == list2[index]` checks automatically, instead of manually hard-coding those 3 comparing statements in there. And **not loose** any performance?

I tried to replace this **hard-coded if statement** with this code down below, but it's a few times slower than the hardcoded way:

```
if all((n + a == b) for a, b in zip(list1[:amount_of_checks], list2[:amount_of_checks])):
```

#### So is there a way to:

- make it not hard-coded (use a variable's value to generate specified amount of check)
- retain performance

### Update:

The first list is always the same, the second list always has random values, so I want it to go through the specified range of numbers `n` (100, 101, 102, ...) and find the first `n` that would satisfy ALL the checks (find the 2nd list that has the same values as the first list)

I want it to work with all the operations, like +,-,*,/,% etc

Comment: Why are you looping over `n`?  `list2[0] - list1[0]` is the only value it can possibly have.

Comment: @jasonharper well, I want it to go through the specified range of numbers `n` (100, 101, 102, ...) and find the first `n` that would satisfy ALL the checks

Comment: Please add some worked examples, it is not clear what result you are trying to get.

Comment: Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).  `zip(list1[:amount_of_checks], list2[:amount_of_checks])` can be rewritten as `zip(islice(list1, amount_of_checks), islice(list2, amount_of_checks))`.  This avoids creating sublists just to pass them as arguments to `zip`.  If the condition for `all` exits early this can have a nice performance boost.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I think it would be better to `islice` the `zip` object

Comment: @vaultah: That would be cleaner.  It would look like this: `islice(zip(list1, list2), amount_of_checks)`. (Note: This only works in Python 3 where `zip` returns an iterator.  If anyone wants to use this in Python 2 they should use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to accomplish the same.).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you kind sir, the method is working and is really fast! Please post it as the answer I'll accept it

Comment: @vaultah thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a key point here. You do not need to guess the size of your delta. You can rearrange `n + list1[x] == list2[x]` to read `n == list2[x] - list1[x]`. This way, there is only one or no values of `n` which make all the elements you want to compare equal to each other. You can do something like:

```
def find_n(amount_of_checks, list1, list2):
    deltas = set(a - b for a, b in zip(list1[:amount_of_checks], list2[:amount_of_checks]))
    if len(deltas) == 1:
        return next(deltas)
```

This is a very simplified approach. One improvement that might help with performance would be to use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of the index `[1:amount_of_checks]` since that would avoid allocating a new pair of lists.

Your original code only allows `n` within a certain range. If this is something you want and not just an artifact, you can add that test as well:

```
def find_n(amount_of_checks, list1, list2, n_start, n_end):
    deltas = set(b - a for a, b in zip(list1[1:amount_of_checks], list2[1:amount_of_checks]))
    if len(deltas) == 1:
        n = next(deltas)
        if n >= n_start and n < n_end:
            return next(deltas)
```

**Update in response to your update**

You should be able to write all the operations besides modulo in the same way:

- For `n - list1[x] == list2[x]`, use `deltas = set(a + b ...`
- For `n * list1[x] == list2[x]`, use `deltas = set(b / a ...`
- For `n / list1[x] == list2[x]`, use `deltas = set(b * a ...`
- For `n**list1[x] == list2[x]`, use `deltas = set(b ** (1 / a) ...`
- etc.

The problem with modulo is that it does not have a unique inverse operation. I do not remember enough number theory at this point to say if there will be a faster solution than just using @Steven's answer using a direct application of `all`, `islice` and `zip`, but I suspect not.

Comment: Thanks, your method is actually mad fast. it takes 0.000007 instead of 0.0001 when I do: `islice(zip(list1, list2), amount_of_checks)` 
wow

Comment: If that's the case, you can always change your selection :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why doesn't your method works with modulo operation, like n % list (perhaps we can't rearrange it as with n + list operation?)

Comment: Oh. I forgot you wanted to wrap around. You don't mention that *anywhere* in your question, but you accepted an answer with modulo. What's up with that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that and then edited the question. Could you also suggest a way to do this with `n % list` operation, not just `n + list`? I'm not sure why it's not working. Is it possible?

Comment: @Un1. Could you please edit that into the question? It would help future readers understand why the selected answer does not appear to address the question itself. In the meantime, I will try to come up with a similar answer.

Comment: I will edit it now. Thanks. All I want to do is to go through the range of numbers `n` and compare all `n + list1` (or `n - list1` or  `n % list1`) with list2 and return first list2 that has the same values (meaning is equal to  `n % list1`)

Comment: @Un1. I updated my answer. I could not find a fast solution for modulo, but I could for all the other, invertible operators.

Comment: thanks for allocating your knowledge to solving this problem, I appreciate it. I'll try something else for modulo then

Answer (score 2):

```
if all((n % a == b) for a, b in zip(list1[:amount_of_checks], list2[:amount_of_checks]))
```

This code is slow because the slices `list1[:amount_of_checks]` and `list2[:amount_of_checks]` iterate `amount_of_checks` times to create sublists that get thrown away.  It's particularly unfortunate when `(n % a == b)` evaluates to `False` on an early iteration because `all` is happy to shorcut evaluation in these situations, but you've already paid the performance penalty in the sublist creation.

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid the performance penalty of creating the sublists:

```
zip(islice(list1, amount_of_checks), islice(list2, amount_of_checks))
```

This can be streamlined by switching the order or `zip` and `islice`

```
islice(zip(list1, list2), amount_of_checks)
```

Put it all together and you get

```
if all((n % a == b) for a, b in islice(zip(list1, list2), amount_of_checks))
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need to swap `islice` and `zip`: `zip(islice(list1, amount_of_checks), list2)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin `all` function

```
if all(list1[i]-list2[i]==n for i in range(start, end)):
    # Whatever you want to do
```

Comment: This would create a list of `N` elements even if the first pair of elements doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: Well, if you have a cleaner looking alternative go on :)

Comment: To address @vaultah's objection remove the brackets from your list comprehension and turn it into a generator expression: `if all(list1[i]-list2[i]==n for i in range(start, end)):`

Comment: problem addressed!

Answer (score 1):

```
if all([(n + list1[i] == list2[i]) for i in range(start, end)]):
    # ...
```

Just change `start` and `end` according to your range

However, of course this isn't quite as fast as writing out all the conditions by hand. If we measure execution time using `timeit` with some sample values, it becomes obvious:

```
timeit.timeit('all([(2 + 1 == 3) for _ in range(0, 5)])', number=10000)
> 0.008927443002903601
timeit.timeit('2 + 1 == 3 and 2 + 1 == 3 and 2 + 1 == 3 and 2 + 1 == 3 and 2 + 1 == 3', number=10000)
> 0.0011130370003229473
```

so keep that in mind (since I don't know how high your performance needs are)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but it's 10 times slower then the slice method.

Comment: Yes I agree, the other method seems better ;)